# Binding returns default value (set with registerDefaults:) instead of zero

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings, null

**Here's my setup:**

- `myTextField` is bound to a key in the Shared User Defaults Controller. The user can only enter numbers in the text field.
- Each time my application loads, I load default preferences (from the app's Resources folder) using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults: ... ]`.
- `myMenuItem`'s title is bound to the same key in the Shared User Defaults Controller.

**The issue:**

When `myTextField` is empty, `myMenuItem` receives the default value that was loaded using `registerDefaults:` instead of some value that represents the empty field (I would expect 0 or `nil`).

For example, when the `NSTextField` is empty the menu item receives "2", the value that was loaded using `registerDefaults:`, instead of some value that means that the field is empty.

If I comment the `registerDefaults:` code, the binding returns `nil` as I would expect when there is nothing in the `NSTextField`.

I tried to mess around with many of the bindings' settings as well as experiment with placeholder values and I looked at the Cocoa Bindings and User Defaults docs but I could not find the solution.

**Expected behavior:**

- When the text field is empty, I want `myMenuItem` to reflect that instead of using the default value that was registered using `registerDefaults:`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some hints from the nice folks at irc.freenode.org #macdev and found the following to be the solution to my problem:

Creating a subclass of NSFormatter (or NSNumberFormatter in my case) and overriding `getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:` as follows overrides the default behaviour of returning `nil` (which makes the binding use the registered default value) to instead return 0 when the text field is empty.

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        *anObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [super getObjectValue:anObject forString:string errorDescription:error];
    }
}
```

A NSValueTransformer subclass' reverse conversion method would have also worked for this.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

The solution above does not work for strings. That is, if your userDefault value is a string and you've bound that to the value of an NSTextField and you subclass NSFormatter and do this:

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        *anObject = nil;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You'll find that when the NSTextField is empty, the binding is set to whatever value you originally registered using -registerDefaults: rather than to an empty string or a nil value. I attempted to use *anObject = [NSNull null]; as well, but that didn't work either --- the binding is still set to the original, default value.

I ended up setting *anObject = @" "; (a string with a single space) in the code above, so that when the textField is empty, the value in the userDefaults pList is set to the string: @" ". I then check for that string everywhere that uses that userDefault value and respond appropriately (ignore the single space and treat it as if the userDefault value were empty).

It's an ugly hack, but the only way I can find to work around this issue currently. I'm posting it here in case someone else stumbles on this thread. If you ask me, binding an NSTextField to a userDefault should bloody well set that userDefault to an empty string when the textField is empty! Why Apple chose to do it the way they did is beyond me.